# How to insert a NSButton into a NSTextView? (inline)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, button, nstextview

I have a NSTextView and a custom NSButton. What I want to do is to insert that button (60x16 in size) to the end of the NSTextView.
How can I do something like that? I've been trying to search around on how to do this but I'm not getting anywhere. 
Where should I begin? Thanks

Comment: Does it *need* to be inside the textView? What is your goal?

Comment: Yes, I really need to insert a button into the NSTextView. When pressed, the button will show a popover with some additional information about the text that's behind it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this question is pretty similar to yours:

[Buttons inside an NSTextView / NSTextStorage](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/148790-buttons-inside-an-nstextview-nstextstorage.html)

**Quote from the question:**

> *how do I get an NSButton to appear inside the text and react to
>   clicks?*

Note that the issue is not fully solved there, but it seems the OP got a good head start. Hopefully you can take some clues from the discussion.

**Here is one answer:**

> NSTextAttachment holds the contents of an attachment; it is the value
>   of the NSAttachmentAttributeName attribute for the
>   NSAttachmentCharacter in the attributed string.  The contents are
>   usually given by an NSFileWrapper, but this is not required; you can
>   create an empty NSTextAttachment with a nil file wrapper.
>
> NSTextAttachmentCell handles display and user interaction for the
>   attachment.  By default an NSTextAttachment will create an
>   NSTextAttachmentCell to display itself, depending on the contents of
>   the attachment; in the generic case this will just be an image cell
>   displaying an icon.
>
> If you wish, however, you can supply a custom NSTextAttachmentCell for
>   your attachment.  It need not be an member of the class
>   NSTextAttachmentCell; it only needs to conform to the
>   NSTextAttachmentCell protocol.  Actually, even that is not strictly
>   necessary; it only needs to implement a few of the basic methods for
>   sizing and drawing.  Most cells already do this.
>
> You will, however, need to deal with mouse events yourself.  The
>   methods you'll probably want to implement would be
>   wantsToTrackMouseForEvent:inRect:ofView:atCharacterIndex: and
>   trackMouse:inRect:ofView:atCharacterIndex:.  The character index here
>   should let you determine which portion of the text is relevant.

Comment: The link does not work anymore. Gives 404