# How to display elements inside NSCollectionView with various shapes

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin, nscollectionview

I am a rookie Cocoa guy. I need to design and implement a view which will show collection of labels on Mac OS using Xamarin. These labels will have a text and color associated with them. When shown inside the view, label should expand till it covers whole text and it will be shown with background and foreground colors.

I have attached the picture of this user control on Windows, you can see that labels inside the StackPanel are expanding till they cover the whole text. Hope this gives better idea about my ask.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The $64,000 question is "are these labels controls?" In other words, do you expect the user to click on these to do something, or are they just for display?

If your answer is "just for display", the solution is super simple: Use an `NSTextField` and programmatically add attributed text (`NSAttributedString`) to it. Attributed text attaches display properties to runs of text within the field; properties like "background color".

If you want these to be buttons that you can click on, then things get a lot more complicated.

Since you apparently want the button layout to "flow", you might look into imbedding buttons (well, button cells) into an `NSTextField` using attachments. This is normally how non-text content (say, an image) can be inserted, but with some fiddling it can actually be anything a control cell can draw. See [How to insert a NSButton into a NSTextView? (inline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723803/how-to-insert-a-nsbutton-into-a-nstextview-inline).

Warning: this is not a "rookie" topic and will involve control cells and custom event handling.

If *I* were doing this, I'd probably just create `NSButton` objects for each label (choosing an appropriate style/look like `NSRecessedBezelStyle`), create a custom subclass of `NSView` to contain them, and then override the `layout` method to position all of the buttons the way I want.

To be thorough, I'd also override the intrinsic size methods so the whole thing could participate in auto-layout, based on the number and size of buttons it contained.